# Copy cursor object in Python

Tags: python, deep-copy, database-cursor

I am working on a Trac-Plugin...

To retrieve my data I create a cursor object and get the result table like this:

```
 db = self.env.get_db_cnx()
 cursor = db.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT...")
```

Now the result is being used in 3 different functions. My Problem is now that the cursor is being cleaned out while looping through the first time (like it is told here http://packages.python.org/psycopg2/cursor.html)

I then tried to copy the cursor object, but this failed too. the `copy(cursor)` function seems to have problem with a big dataset and the function `deepcopy(cursor)` fails anyway (according to this bug http://bugs.python.org/issue1515).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can't you store results in the first loop iteration and later re-use them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Storing the values from *any finite iterable* is simple:

```
results = list(cursor)
```

Iterate over the iterable and store the results in a list. This list can be iterated over as many times as necessary.

You don't need a copy of the cursor, just a copy of the results of the query.

For this specific case, you should do what 9000 suggests in his comment -- use the cursors built-in functionality to get the results of a list, which should be as fast or faster than manually calling `list`.

Comment: Alternatively, one can explicitly call `cursor.fetchall()` and get a list of tuples, too.

Comment: If I do it with `list(cursor)` I get no data while looping through with `for a1,a2,a3,a4 in dbList`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind. solved  it by using `cursor.fechall()` Thanks to 9000 and agf!

Comment: This solution works, yes, but it is not fantastic due to the fact that it is totally non-scalable. If you are querying for a large result set, you would not want to pull the entire set into memory (a list of a hundred million things gets rather large).

Comment: @dpb If you want to use the results multiple times without performing the query multiple times, you're going to have to store them in memory. It's true that you should generally be structuring your code so that's not necessary, but often the result set does fit in memory, so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid looping through the data an extra time you could try wrapping it in a generator:

```
def lazy_execute(sql, cursor=cursor):
    results = []
    cursor.execute(sql)
    def fetch():
        if results:
            for r in results:
                yield r
            raise StopIteration()
        else:
            for r in cursor:
                results.append(r)
                yield r
            raise StopIteration()

    return fetch
```

This essentially creates a list as you need it, but lets you call the same function everywhere, safely. You would then use this like so:

```
results = lazy_execute(my_sql):
for r in results():
    "do something with r"
```

This is almost certainly an over-engineered premature-optimization, though it does have the advantage of the same name meaning the same thing in every case, as opposed to generating a new list and then the same data having two different names.

I think if I were going to argue for using this I would use the same-names argument, unless the data set was pretty huge, but if it's huge enough to matter then there's a good chance you don't want to store it all in memory anyway.

Also it's completely untested.

Comment: The processor overhead of doing this in Python vs. letting it happen in C can be significant for a large list. You can remove the overhead after the first pass by rewriting everything after the first two lines as `return lambda: iter(results) if results else (results.append(r) or r for r in cursor)`. The `else` generator expression works because `append` always returns `None`, so the value of `r` will always be used. Your "same name" argument doesn't make sense. After `cursor.execute(my_sql); results = cursor.fetchall()` the data only exits in `results`.